# What do I do with my local csv files when deploying Python Panel Application to Google Cloud

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, deployment, google-cloud-storage, panel

Hello I am trying to deploy my panel application with google cloud. I am just wondering how do I deal with my local csv files I am importing as data frames. I use `df = pd.read_csv("some/local/directory")` to create my data frames. And I use functions like os.path.join How do I handle this data when deploying? My data is all .csv files around 7gb.

Answer (score 0):

Upload your csv files to [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage), it can be accessed from other Cloud Services.

Try [Python Client for Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/storage/latest) and refer example [Reading and writing to Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/read-write-to-cloud-storage)

If you are running your application in Compute Engine VM, one more option is [Cloud Fuse](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse) - you can mount storage bucket as a file system in VM.

Make sure to give [storage bucket access](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/using-iam-permissions) to [Service Account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts) you are using.